# Use layout for certain routes in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to maintain a section of my app available for all pages (most of the pages actually)
to do that I wrapped the routes in a Layout

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/login" exact strict component={Login}/>
    <Layout>
        <Route path="/list" exact strict component={List}/>
        <Route path="/settings" exact strict component={Settings}/>
    </Layout>
</Router>
```

the Layout component looks like this

```
class Layout extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div>this box should be visible in all pages using layout</div>
                <div>{this.props.children}</div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

this work perfectly fine. the only poblem is when I go to /login
is rendering the Login component and also the Layout component.

I shouldn´t render the Layout if is not for one of the ¨protected¨ routes.
is there a way to achieve that without moving the layout inside of the List of Settings component?
the reason for this is because the box that´s fixed in all pages makes one API request and there´s no need to do that same API call for /list and /settings. I do it only once.

hope this makes sense to you. thank you!

**update:**
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.1"

Comment: which version of react-router do you use?

Comment: I'm not sure, but could Switch help here? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch. If you are using react-router of course. And yes, it's version could help. As I understand `Switch` it should stop on the `/login` `<Route />`.

Comment: I´m using "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1" thank you!

Comment: I also use react-router-dom and my answer below works pretty well.

Comment: in my case the Route is a child of the Layout.

Comment: When I did that, I had layouts/styles pollute one another. As far as I remember, I didn't dig too much into it to confirm but functionally, it's because Route has a path in which if it's hit it renders the component supplied so if you have your layout outside of that it is always rendered (or that's at least how I remember the problem when I ran into it a while back) which is why I have my own route components that use React.Route so in theory the layouts will only be rendered when the path matches.

Comment: @handsome have you tried my answer yet? I feel like it'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done a fair bit of research on the subject and came up with this. I have it set up in my routes:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
// import PublicRoute, PrivateRoute, Login, Private
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <PublicRoute exact path='/login' component={Login} />
    <PrivateRoute path='/private' component={Private} />
  </Switch>
<Router>
```

Then in my privateRoute.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
// import useAuth and PrivateLayout
export default ({ componet: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { token } = useAuth() // wrapper I wrote to handle auth
  if (!token) return <Redirect to='/login' />
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
      <PrivateLayout><Component {...props} /></PrivateLayout>
    )} />
  )
}
```

And my publicRoute.js is similar but without authentication. My layouts are a simple wrapper, all you need to do is include children:

```
export default ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Topbar />
      <Sidebar />
      {children}
    </>
  )
```

Note: For those who don't know `<>` is the shorthand for `<React.Fragment>`.